# Back button showing as different colour on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

To experiment with the back button in a navigation controller set up, I added a button programmatically without using storyboard and without using the default navigation bar and back button you get for free with the navigation controller.

In App Delegate I simply said:

```
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

I set the button to a simple black and white image icon - but when I run it in the simulator the image shows as blue.

Does anyone know why this might be? It seems to still be picking up the navigation controller colour of blue but I have set the `NavigationBarHidden` to be true.

Comment: You need to set the `tintColor` in `viewWillAppear` or set it hidden there.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I set the tintColor and that worked. Can you tell me why the image was picking up the blue tint, when it was a custom button?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem takes an image from your UIButton and sets it as a template image allowing the bar button to have tintColours. By default, it tints anything you set to it unless you specify the tintColor as white.

Comment: I didn't think UIBarButtonItem would be involved here since I added a custom button. Is this UIBarButtonItem still working behind the scenes then, just by nature of my using a navigation controller? I set the tintColor of the backButton to black in viewWillAppear and it worked - is that what you mean? Or did you mean I should set the tintColor of NavigationBar as white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from assets, make sure the photo is selected and go to attributes inspector and change “render image as” to Original, same applies for tab bar items images